# GCM notifications only arrive to some devices

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app in the store and it uses GCM push notifications. The problem is that notifications only reach some of the devices I send them to. In particular I have noticed that they arrive to tablets and not to phones, but I have only tried two tablets and two phones, so this could or could not be meaningful. Both tablets have Android 5.0 or 5.1, as well as one of the phones. The other phone has 4.4.

The devices register successfully to notifications and send their ID to my server. I get no error when sending the notifications from the server, but they never arrive. I tried with wifi and 3G connections, both with no luck.

I found the code to do this somewhere in the web, but can't really remember where. The thing is I don't fully understand how it works, but at the time it seemed good enough, given I tested on one of the devices that receives the notifications. I will post all the relevant code, perhaps someone can tell me if something is wrong.

**This is my manifest (removed irrelevant parts)**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>

    <permission
        android:name="edu.galileo.estudiantes.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="edu.galileo.estudiantes.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        ...

        <receiver
            android:name=".util.EstudiantesGcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="my.package.name.gcm" /> <!-- I do have my actual package name here-->
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".util.EstudiantesGcmListenerService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is the Receiver**

```
public class EstudiantesGcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                EstudiantesGcmListenerService.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**This is the IntentService**

```
public class EstudiantesGcmListenerService extends IntentService
{
    public EstudiantesGcmListenerService() {
        super("EstudiantesGcmListenerService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();        

        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("msg"))
        {
            String message = extras.getString("msg");
            new Handler().post(() -> showNotification("Bla bla", message));

        }
        EstudiantesGcmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }

    void showNotification(String title, String desc)
    {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        long id = getLastNotificationId(this) + 1;
        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                           .setContentTitle(title)
                                           .setContentText(desc)
                                           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                                           .setTicker(desc)
                                           .setAutoCancel(true).setVibrate(new long[]{300, 300, 300, 300});

        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        b.setContentIntent(intent);
        manager.notify((int) id, b.build());
        storeLastNotificationId(id, this);
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try to reinstall your app on phones?

Comment: I have deleted it and re-uploaded it with Android Studio (Can't download from the store, because it would point to production servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Google recommends using **GCMReceiver** instead of **WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

2.And you have to extend your service with **GcmListenerService**

3.Also, we have to use **InstanceId**, because gcm.register() is deprecated.(It will still generate you the gcm key).

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Their sample code for usage "https://github.com/google/gcm"

I was facing similar issue a week ago, especially in Micromax and Infocus phones. Now, the notifications are just working fine.

Comment: You were right about GCMListenerService, I ended up not using a GCMReceiver subclass, but referencing com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver in the manifest and adding and intent filter to my GcmListenerService, as it is done here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the problem, the GCM works on the devices installed with Android 5.0+ and not on 4.4.x versions.

In addition to the changes suggested by @m0rpheus5, Please check you see that the latest version of Google Play Services is installed on the devices  with 4.4.x versions. Most of the time updating it to the latest version works!!

Hope that helps!

Comment: After doing what is stated in my comment to the other answer, it works even for 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I have started using **GcmListenerService** as per new sample provided by Google, then I have started facing strange issue.

I can receive GCM on few devices but I can't receive GCM on QMobile which is a local brand with Android 4.4.2, but my older application with **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** implementation is working fine on same device.

Any advice ?

Comment: The same thing happened to me... Just check out my comment to the accepted answer to know how I fixed it. It seems to work fine now.